# How to load native library to android library project

Tags: android, native, loadlibrary

First, my project structure is like this:

**Android project A --> Android Library project B（contains some native so library） --> Java library C**.

1. how the project A reference the android library project B:
   [image]
2. The native library in the android library project B.

[image]

3. how the Android Library project B is library:
   [image]
4. The load library code (in the android library project B) :

   System.loadLibrary("G72x");

   System.loadLibrary("H264Android");
5. The crash log :

   ```
   12-27 20:32:51.698: E/AndroidRuntime(11589): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1694
   12-27 20:32:51.698: E/AndroidRuntime(11589): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:    InitDecoder
   12-27 20:32:51.698: E/AndroidRuntime(11589):    at com.xx.xxx.media.H264Decoder.InitDecoder(Native Method)
   12-27 20:32:51.698: E/AndroidRuntime(11589):    at com.xx.xxx.media.VideoParseThread.getH264(VideoParseThread.java:131)
   12-27 20:32:51.698: E/AndroidRuntime(11589):    at com.xxx.xxx.media.VideoParseThread.run(VideoParseThread.java:46)
   ```

Now when the application run the code that need the so library, it crashed. I have read some answers, but it's still not resolved.

If the all the library b project is in the project A, it worked well.

Any help will be appreciated, this problem drives me crazy, i know it should have one solution, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

First:
Horrible explaination of your project and description of your project structure.
Second:
Make sure it is exported in your build settings.
If you explain more precise, how your structure is, maybe with Screenshots, then I can narrow down my explanation of your mistake

Edit:

Under your "project properties" go into "java build path" and then "order and export".
In here your project needs to be present and marked.

Comment: Okay much better.
Your reference in project A to project B, is not enough. Edited the answer